# Starting count down timer app

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

In iPhone, under clock, we've count down timer and when timer expires it plays alarm.
So, from my app, I want to start the count down timer. So whether my app is running or not, I'll get alarm. 
Apart from UILocalNotification, is there any solution?

Comment: If you want it to work also if your app gets killed, UILocalNotification is your (only) friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I make my comment an answer...

If you want it to work also if your app gets killed, `UILocalNotification` is your (only) friend.